# Code only works when I put it into body instead of head

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn some web programming and I'm having this issue.

I use FullCalendar on my site and I placed creation of calendar on separate JavaScript file. That's funktiot.js. Then I have my index.php file which includes first JQuery and then my funktiot.js. After that I call my calendar creation function. However it's only working when I put includes and method call to body.

E.g this won't work

```
<head>
  <script src='libs/fullcalender/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script src="libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <script src='libs/fullcalender/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
  <script src='libs/fullcalender/fullcalendar.js'></script>
  <script src="libs/fullcalender/lang/fi.js"></script>

  <script src="js/funktiot.js"></script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).load(luoKalenteri("#calendar", <?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>));
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
         <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

but this does

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
         <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>

  <script src='libs/fullcalender/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script src="libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <script src='libs/fullcalender/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
  <script src='libs/fullcalender/fullcalendar.js'></script>
  <script src="libs/fullcalender/lang/fi.js"></script>

  <script src="js/funktiot.js"></script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
      luoKalenteri("#calendar", <?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>);
  </script>
</body>
```

I thought the first one would work as well as I use $(document).load and include JQuery before everything else? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to wait for your page to be [ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). When it goes through the head and executes the JS, calendar has not been rendered yet. You can leave the scripts in header if you want, but you should not have the actual JS being executed UNTIL you know the page is ready for it to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).load(luoKalenteri("#calendar", <?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>))
```

This will not work in the head. Break it out by going inner to outer:

```
var result = luoKalenteri("#calendar", <?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>);
// result => undefined
$(document).load(result);
// Or
$(document).load(undefined);
```

Since `#calendar` is not ready at the time the head is parsed `luoKalenteri` will probably crash or do nothing.

Instead you should be passing a function *not the result of a function call* to `load()`:

```
$(document).load(function() {
  luoKalenteri("#calendar", <?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>);
});
```

#### Off-Topic nitpick

Injecting PHP in the middle of code is bad form. It make readability difficult and can be a source of headache when trying to debug. Better to push all PHP injections into a central place like so:

```
<script>
  var CONFIG = {
    calendarId: <?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>
  };
</script>
<script>
  $(document).load(function() {
    luoKalenteri("#calendar", CONFIG.calendarId);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry for stupid question. I see it now, I understood that syntax wrong. Obviously I was passing result of function, not function itself. Thank you for explanation! Also thanks for the nitpick too, I will absolutely take that into use now. I hated that PHP injection but just went with it as had no better ways in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has to be executed when the page initialization has finished.

Jquery has a function to ease things up:

```
$( document ).ready()
```

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

As stated there: "A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute."

Answer (score 0):

try using `$(document).ready(function() {});`

**Reason**:
Basically your javascript code runs even before page completely loads and DOM is created when put in head.

Comment: Oh, that's what I tried but it didn't work. Or actually I thought I did that! What I actually did was $(document).ready(luoKalenteri("#calendar", <?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>)); when I should have done         $(document).ready(function() {
      luoKalenteri("#calendar", <?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>)
    });

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { luoKalenteri(...); }); should work.

Answer (score 0):

just wrap you code like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // write your code here
});
```

by doing this, your code will execute once the DOM has loaded!

Answer (score -2):

You should always put your script tags at the bottom of your body. It makes the page Load to slowly if there at the top so really you don't have a problem.

Comment: This does not answer the original question.